# Why is my function using lodash _.forEach returning the same value?

Tags: javascript, testing, foreach, lodash, vitest

I am currently learning lodash and vitest. I created a simple function and an inline test with it.

Here is the test and the function below it

```
import _ from 'lodash'

if (import.meta.vitest) {
    const { describe, expect, it } = import.meta.vitest;

    describe('#name', () => {
        it('should..', () => {
            expect(
                collectForEach([1, 2], function (n) {
                    return n * 2;
                }),
            ).toEqual([2, 4]);
        });
    });
}

function collectForEach(collection, iteratee) {
    return _.forEach(collection, iteratee);
}
```

As stated in the test, I am expecting to return an array of [2,4]. However the test fails saying that the actual return is [1,2].
Am I misunderstanding how to use _.forEach or am I making a different type of error?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`lodash.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map).

E.g.

```
import assert from 'assert'
import _ from 'lodash'

const collectMap = (collection, iteratee) => _.map(collection, iteratee)

const actual = collectMap([1,2], n => n * 2);
const expected = [2,4]
assert.deepStrictEqual(actual, expected, 'should pass')
console.log('actual: ', actual)
```

Execution result:

```bash
actual:  [ 2, 4 ]
```